# Customize "for json auto" to get customized result

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I am having below codes in SQL Server

```
declare @output table ([key] nvarchar(max) , val nvarchar(max))
insert into @output values ('key1' , 'val1' )
insert into @output values ('key2' , 'val2' )
select * from @output for json auto
```

which returns below result:

```
[{"key":"key1","val":"val1"},{"key":"key2","val":"val2"}]
```

I am wondering if there is any way to change my json result to something like nelow:

```
{"Key1": "val1" , "key2": "val2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this using `FOR JSON` unless you use dynamic SQL.

However, it's much easier to just use `STRING_AGG`. You need to make sure to properly escape using `STRING_ESCAPE`

```sql
SELECT '{' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(o.[key], 'json') + '":"' + STRING_ESCAPE(o.val, 'json') + '"', ',') + '}'
FROM @output o;
```

Note that if you wanted a JSON array aggregated by a third column, say `Id`, you can use `STRING_AGG` a second time

```sql
SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(o.obj, ',') + ']'
FROM
    SELECT obj = '{"id":"' + STRING_ESCAPE(o.id, 'json') + '",' + STRING_AGG('"' + STRING_ESCAPE(o.[key], 'json') + '":"' + STRING_ESCAPE(o.val, 'json') + '"', ',') + '}'
    FROM @output o
    GROUP BY Id
) o;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
select '{'+string_agg('"'+[key]+'" : "'+val+'"' ,  ',')+'}' from @output
```